# Python : get all exe files in current directory and run them?

Tags: python, teamcity-5.1

First of all this is not homework, I'm in a desperate need for a script that will do the following, my problem is, I've never had to deal with python before so I barely know how to use it - and I need it to launch unit tests in TeamCity via a commandline build runner

What I need exactly is :

a *.bat file that will run the script

a python script that will :

- get all *_test.exe files in the current working directory
- run all the files which were the result of the search

Best regards

Comment: Why do you need to involve Python, can't you simply use the batch file to start those programs?

Comment: We're adding tests daily, we don't want to edit the batch file every time we add something new, we need a flexible solution

Comment: What error or problem were you getting with the code I posted?

Comment: @ Noctis I'll let you know tomorrow once I return to the office

Comment: Have you found out what the problem was with my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import glob, os
def solution():
    for fn in glob.glob("*_text.exe"):
        os.startfile(fn)
```

Comment: this solution worked. Another question that I have is : can I make the script wait till the current process finishes execution ?

Comment: add `import subprocess` and change `os.startfile(fn)` to `p = subprocess.Popen([fn]); p.wait()`. p.wait() will also give you the return code so you could do something like `if p.wait() == 0: print 'Success'; else: print 'Fail'`

Comment: @gnibbler : what if i wanted to do this on the whole hard disk, rather than just the current directory.

Comment: @thecreator232, you can use `os.walk` to loop over all the directories on your hard disk.

Answer (score 3):

If you copy this into a file, the script should do as you asked.

```
import os       # Access the operating system.

def solution(): # Create a function for later.
    for name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if name.lower().endswith('_test.exe'):
            os.startfile(name)

solution()      # Execute this inside the CWD.
```

Comment: there's a problem with this solution :)